# Convert timestamp list to datetime list

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

Within my program I filter for dates. I receive them as a list of timestamps:

```
timestamp = [1545730073]
```

The type of this list is:

```
print(type(timestamp))

Out: <class 'int'>
```

To convert this list into a list of datetime / datetime64, I tried several versions of the following code:

```
dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
print(dt_object)
```

or

```
dt_object = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item) for item in timestamp]
print(dt_object)
```

I need this type to extract the date later by the following function:

```
import datetime

dt_object = dt_object.date()
print(dt_object)
```

The output of this would and should be finally `Out: 2018-12-25`.

Do you guys have a recommendation to tweak my code to accomplish this task?

Comment: you mean: `dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp[0]).date()` ?? this assumes timestamp is a list

Comment: If using `pandas` as your tags suggest, you can try `pd.to_datetime(timestamp, unit='s')`

Comment: @anky_91 Please post as question. Your comment solved my issue. I want to give you the credits. ;) Thank you as well Chris, but didn't need seconds. :)

Comment: @Mike_H thank you. however, i just added `.date()` , which I feel comment is the way to go. Thanks for your intent though. Cheers..!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming the timestamps are in a list of strings/int:

```
import datetime as dt
timestamp = [1545730073,1645733473]   # or timestamp = ['1545730073','1645733473']

for ts in timestamp:
    print(dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).date())
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
2018-12-25
2022-02-25
```

**EDIT**:

Using list comprehension:

```
print([dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).date() for ts in timestamp])
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 12, 25), datetime.date(2022, 2, 25)]
```

**EDIT 2**:

If you want to replace the timestamps, using `enumerate()`:

```
import datetime as dt
timestamp = [1545730073,1645733473]   # or timestamp = ['1545730073','1645733473']

for indx, ts in enumerate(timestamp):
    timestamp[indx] = dt.datetime.fromtimestamp(int(ts)).date()

print(timestamp)
```

**OUTPUT**:

```
[datetime.date(2018, 12, 25), datetime.date(2022, 2, 25)]
```

Comment: Your answer really helped! Can you give an example on how to save the output back into the timestamp list? That would finalize for my aimed functionality!

Comment: @Mike_H Not quiet clear on that, do you want a new list with the dates? An example would be helpful!

Comment: Let me elaborate more clearly. I need the printed output as a list ```timestamp = [2018-12-25, 2022-02-25]```. Simple as that. But somehow my brain is stuck on this little problem...

Comment: @Mike_H Ha, happens, I've added an edit 2 for that in my answer! :)

Comment: Wonderful! I hope this will fix my big programme where I need to run this problem in. Maybe I will come back to you with another issue. :D

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/190910/discussion-between-mike-h-and-dirtybit).

Answer (score 0):

get string date '2018-12-25', like this

```
dt_object.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
```

if you got timestamp list, should like this:

```
timestamp = [1545730073, 1545730073]
dates = [datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(item).date() for item in timestamp]
```

Comment: I need it as datetime not as string. Thank you!

Comment: convert if it is a int obj, for else should convert each element, not the list

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use map,

```
dt_object = list(map(datetime.date.fromtimestamp, timestamp))
```

Answer (score -2):

do not write timestamp inside square brackets.
Try this code work properly.

```
timestamp =1545730073
dt_object = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(timestamp)
dt_object = dt_object.date()
print(dt_object)
```

Comment: I get the timestamps within a list. So this answer is not applicable for my problem context.